# Always a double root between "no roots" and "at least one root"?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Let $f(x,y)$ be a real bivariate polynomial. Suppose that $f(x,.)$
has no real roots when $x<0$, but has at least one real root when
$x>0$. Does it automatically follow that $f(0,.)$ has a double root ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, consider $f(x,y)=1-xy^2$. $ $

Comment: In that counterexample, the roots go to infinity when $x\to 0$. Which leads me to wonder what happens when the roots stay in a bounded interval, I updated my initial question

Comment: And it might have been preferable to ask *another* one.

Comment: That’s a debatable issue, I myself have no opinion on the matter. I’ll put it into another question since you suggested it, but I predict that some other people will say : "it might have been preferable to stay in the same question".

Comment: I invented nothing about the matter, instructions on the site clearly suggest to do so (and common sense, I might add). Anyway, no big deal.