# If a thread is pulled out of a floating blob of water, must the thread be tangent to the surface of the blob at some point?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

My motivation is the recent question I just answered, and my answer use too many hypothesis that I considered superfluous: [Always "one double root" between "no root" and "at least one root" ? (Second version)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879685/always-one-double-root-between-no-root-and-at-least-one-root-second-ver)

So now on to the question:

> Consider a differentiable $n$-dimensional manifold $M$.
>
> Let $f:\Bbb
>  S^{k}\rightarrow M$ be a differentiable bijective embedding of the
>   $k$-sphere ($k\leq n$) into $M$.
>
> Let $H:[0,1]\times \Bbb
> > S^{l}\rightarrow M$ be a differentiable function such that
>   $H(t,\cdot)$ is bijective for all $t$ (this is a homotopy of an
>   embedding of a $l$-sphere in $M$).
>
> Further,
>   $\operatorname{range}(H(0,\cdot))$ intersects $\operatorname{range}(f)$
>   but $\operatorname{range}(H(1,\cdot))$ does not intersect
>   $\operatorname{range}(f)$.

The question is: **must there exist a $t$ and a point $p\in M$ such that between the tangent space of $\operatorname{range}(H(t,\cdot))$ at $p$ and the tangent space of $\operatorname{range}(f)$ at $p$, one must contains the other?**

I am sorry if this question have been answered before, or is even a standard theorem, or if this question is poorly phrased. I barely studied differential geometry. Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:** Why the title?

Consider a floating blob of water, and we have a thread submerged in it. Well, for simplicity, the question simply assume that the thread is a loop (which is essentially equivalent to a thread fixed at infinity) and we assume that we are already part way through pulling the thread out, so that part of the thread is the on the surface of the water blob. The surface of the water blob is the image of $f$, and the thread at time $0$ is the image of $H(0,\cdot)$. Now imagine we pull the thread out, it seems like at the last moment where the thread touch the water, at the point it touches, the tangent line to the thread is also tangent to the water surface at that point. Hence the question's title.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the picture. Intuitively, I feel like that should be related to the following: Starting with your initial configuration, suppose we 'draw' a closed curve on the blob which winds around the thread. Then the thread and the curve are linked, and will remain so unless the cross one another. (That's not the same as tangency, but it feels like the right spirit. A strip (with some thickness) instead of a line might be closer to the mark.)

Comment: You probably just want $H(t,\cdot)$ to be injective, right? Also, perhaps you should rid yourself of some trivial cases; for $l = k = 1$ and $M = \mathbb{R}^3$ for instance, you could imagine generically pulling one component of the Hopf link away from the other.

Comment: This is essentially a local question, so you can also replace $M$ by real Euclidean space. I think you need the blob to be $n-1$ dimensional. The point is surely that if the tangent spaces don't coincide at the last $t$ where there is an intersection, then some point of the string is at nonzero depth inside the blob. You'd prove that by looking at the local parametrisation of the surface of the larger-dimensional blob by the tangent space, extending to a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, and using the orientability of the sphere.

Comment: If you have two circular strings (of codimension 2) in $\mathbb{R}^3$, you can pull them apart without achieving coincidence of the tangent space as long as they're not coplanar when they cross. (Fuglede beat me to this, I see.)